# How to disable logging in java security?

Tags: java, security, x509certificate

I have a java web application that recently I had to add some certificates to it to call a web service. After that, after a few hours of start, my web application begin to print a lot of logs like the attached picture so causing the hang of application and tomcat. Could any one please help me to prevent this huge log?

[image: My huge log]

Comment: While you'll have to provide more information, such as what your web app is, what you are using in it, and what your configuration options (if any) are, you might be able to find some useful informaiton [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24422/ssl.htm#SECMG389) . It seems that you might have SSLDebugging enabled, which you can disable by removing some command line options.

Comment: The certificate is only for our web service! I don't know the role of database here?! I am suspicious of the line com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel enableSSL